# Laravel Eloquent - How to create queries with sub query and if satement

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

Here is my query

```
SELECT  
    IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename t WHERE t.field1 = tablename.field1 AND t.field2 IN (50,55,58,60)) = 0,1,0) AS b,
    field3,
    field4,
FROM tablename
WHERE ProductId = ?
```

How do I convert it to laravel eloquent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if you have shown what you've tried.

That said, this should work:

```
$result = App\TablenameModel::where('ProductId', 'your_value_here')
    ->select(
        \DB::raw('IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename t WHERE t.field1 = tablename.field1 AND t.field2 IN (50,55,58,60)) = 0,1,0) AS b'),
        'field3',
        'field4'
    )
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, will try with this.